# What Does MapReactiveUserDetailsService Do in Spring Webflux Security Authentication?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm trying to implement Spring Security authentication on Spring WebFlux app. I have implemented Spring Security authentication on Spring Web before.

When I read articles on how to implement it, I saw `MapReactiveUserDetailsService` bean but there is no explanation about this bean usage. I read the article from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/reactive-spring-security-for-webflux-rest-web-serv) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-reactive).

the bean looks like this:

```
@Bean
public MapReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails user = User
      .withUsername("user")
      .password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
      .roles("USER")
      .build();
    return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(user);
}
```

is there anyone know what it does?

Comment: It is an in-memory implementation of a `ReactiveUserDetailsService`.

Comment: and to add to that comment, here is the source code https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/a4431264e61e01954fdfcb2646942028f2489e65/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/MapReactiveUserDetailsService.java#L34 its basically a just a Map that holds users in memory

Answer (score 0):

It creates a default `in-memory` user. That allows you to test your security. For production goals please change it to such example (kotlin):

```kotlin
@Service
class UserService(private val customerService: CustomerService) : ReactiveUserDetailsService {

    override fun findByUsername(username: String?): Mono<UserDetails> = mono {
        val customer: Customer = customerService.findByEmail(username!!)
            ?: throw BadCredentialsException("Invalid Credentials")

        val authorities: List<GrantedAuthority> = listOf(customer)

        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            customer.email,
            customer.password,
            authorities
        )
    }
}
```